# Flutter FCM crashes when onBackgroundMessage

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to integrate FCM for my flutter app and I was able to successfully do that when `onMessage` and `onResume` but when the app is terminated I get a crash error and the notification won't show, my code is as below:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  print("Handling a background message");
}

     onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

             print(message['data']);
        }
     onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

             print(message['data']);
        }
onBackgroundMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

             print(message['data']);
        }
```

Can anyone help out? Tho I tried to use flutterLocalNotification but I don't know how to parse the data I receive from FCM into it, below is my flutterLocalNotification code:

```
 FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
 
  showNotification() async {
    var android = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel name', 'channel description');
    var iOS = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = NotificationDetails(android: android, iOS: iOS);
   
  }
```

Comment: What is the error you are facing?

Comment: The error message is "app stop working"